# Why the jquery is not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In the head tags i did:

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="carousel.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vertical_slider.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="glow-effect.css">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="jquery.carouFredSel-6.0.4-packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="java_script.js"></script>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    </head>
```

In the bottom in the body tags i did:

```
<div class="vertical-slider-container">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" id="prev" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-up" />
    <div class="slideshow"
         data-cycle-fx="carousel"
         data-cycle-timeout="3000"
         data-cycle-next="#next"
         data-cycle-prev="#prev"
         data-cycle-carousel-visible="3"
         data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true">

        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" id="next" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-down" />
</div>
```

Then in the vertical_slider css file i did:

```
.vertical-slider-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.slideshow {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-slider-nav {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

And in the java_script.js file top i did:

```
$(function() {

    $('.slideshow').cycle();
```

The way it is now i see one image and the next image replacing the other one on same place like fade in.

But in the javascript file if i change the function to:

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'scrollUp'
    });
```

I see the images move up scrolling up one by one.

The problem is that the arrows not working and not in place and i see each time one image and not 3 images.

It should be working like this jsfiddler and i can't figure out why it's not. I don't get any errors.

[Vertical Slider](http://jsfiddle.net/uncb4bs9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It is working.

`Updated fiddle`[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/uncb4bs9/8/

Comment: user3201925 what is [Jsfiddle][1] ? Should be a link ?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want a carousel you have the wrong script included it should be from cycle2 plugin plus the script for the carousel. And then it will work like in the snippet below :)

It should be this two scripts

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
```

Instead of

```
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```js
$('.slideshow').cycle();
```

```css
.vertical-slider-container {
    background: #fff;
    border: 20px solid #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    margin: 40px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 120px;
}

.slideshow {
    background: #fff;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}

.slideshow img {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.vertical-slider-nav {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 40px;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-up {
    top: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -60px;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.vertical-slider-container:hover .vertical-slider-nav-down {
    bottom: -20px;
    opacity: 0.7;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>


<div class="vertical-slider-container">
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-up-01-128.png" id="prev" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-up" />
    <div class="slideshow"
         data-cycle-fx="carousel"
         data-cycle-timeout="3000"
         data-cycle-next="#next"
         data-cycle-prev="#prev"
         data-cycle-carousel-visible="3"
         data-cycle-carousel-vertical="true">

        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach1.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach2.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach3.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach4.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach5.jpg" />
        <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/beach9.jpg" />
    </div>
    <img src="https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/faticons/32/arrow-down-01-128.png" id="next" class="vertical-slider-nav vertical-slider-nav-down" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you put

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.carousel.js"></script>
```

in your code????
please put that and try again. it will work.

for full example please have a look to this http://fiddle.jshell.net/uncb4bs9/3/show/light/ and go to its source code by ctrl+U.